# Como puedo pasar variables desde un archivo php a otro que esta en otro servidor?

Tags: php

Necesito enviar varias variables desde un script a otro script que tengo en otro servidor, por ejemplo el primer script obtiene el titulo contenido y tags de los post creados en la pagina web, entonces necesito poner esos datos en variable para luego enviarlos hacia el otro script que esta en otro servidor, el cual debe de recojer esas variables para luego usarlas en el script.

busque en Internet y encontre algo sobre usar Get pero creo que es necesario hacer clic en el link para que se pueda enviar los datos pero yo quiero solo pasar las variables no necesito ningun formulario ni botones por que todo se hace por medio de codigo no se necesita interaccion con el usuario.

Esto fue lo que encontre:

```
//mandar datos
<a href="http://url.pagina.destino/?variable1=valor1&variable2=valor2">Enlace a página de destino</a>

//obtener datos
<?php
$v1 = $_GET['variable1'];
$v2 = $_GET['variable2'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para reemplazar el "click" que uno haría en el navegador podes usar Curl desde php donde armas el request, lo envias, y podés recibir una respuesta del script remoto confirmando que fue recibido y no hubo errores.

Las variables las podes mandar con metodo GET en la parte "query" del url, o mandarlas con método POST en el body del request.
En el primer caso, en el script remoto,  las levantas con $_GET y en el segundo como $_POST.

Tu ejemplo arma la url como para usar la opción el GET.

**EJEMPLO**

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.pagina.destino/?variable1=" . $v1_validado . "&variable2=" . $v2_validado);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

En $output recibís la respuesta que devolves del otro servidor.

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo de como hacer el Curl con mis parametros por favor?

Comment: Te dejé un ejemplo con la url que tenías en tu código.

Answer (score 0):

tienes dos maneras de hacerlo
si es desde backend puedes usar CURL o Guzzle
si es desde frontend puedes usar una peticion AJAX validando las CORS si es que el otro script esta bajo otro dominio